# Custom tableView header causes cell border to show

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I changed the section header by creating my own view of 23 units high.  For section1 you will see a border for the cell on top of the section header bar.  The border on top of the section1 header bar only shows when i make a custom view for the header, but doesn't show when i use the default gray section header view. Any ideas on why this is?

[image: standard default section header with no border on top]

[image: snapshot of table view]
[image: zoom in of my custom section header]

Answer (score 1):

Hope dis helps:[You can do somethng like this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)